# Do I REALLY need to use ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

If I do need it, I'll have to modify about 15 classes (models and model-manager classes), so I really want to know if I **need** a `ContentProvider`.

Here's where I am:

1. Similar to **Twitter**, I'm getting rows of data from a server, and saving it locally in case the user has no Internet connection. But the ideal way is to always get it from the Server.
2. I am probably **not** going to use `SimpleCursorAdapter` because the rows of data I get from the server includes **URLs**, which means I have to create a custom adapter to display images.
3. I need to load data into the `ListViews` asynchronously because I'm having a `ViewPager` with 3 `Fragments` that shows the **same data** (different filters tho), so, since a `ViewPager` loads 3 `Fragments` into memory, it means 3 queries are executing (and that's most likely the cause of non-smooth swiping).

So far, the way I synchronize data between the App and the Server is:

- `Fragment.onStart()`  executes an `AsyncTask` which returns rows of data formatted as `JSON` data
- Said `AsycTask.onPostExecute()` updates the `List<E>` and calls `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

The issue here is that each time I change tabs, the `onStart()` is called, ergo the `AsyncTask` executes causing the UI not being smooth.

Should I change the way I synchronize data with the Server, or should I use `ContentProvider`?

**EDIT:** as a head up, the reason I'm asking is that `startManagingCursor()` method is depracated. It says to use the `Loader` framework, but it seems it's only available through `ContentProvider`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom `CursorLoader` based on the `SimpleCursorLoader` source code that comes within the support library. You can search this site for more information about writing a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to
>   share your data with other applications. However, you do need your own
>   provider to provide custom search suggestions in your own application.
>   You also need your own provider if you want to copy and paste complex
>   data or files from your application to other applications.

from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: yeah, and yet most of the framework clases are only usable if you use content provider. Sorry but I didn't ask for a copy paste of a block of text I have read multiple times